# Programmatically created Label will not right-justify

Tags: vb6

Creating a label programatically (i.e. not in designer) won't right-align on my form.

```
Set lblStatus = StatusForm.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "lbl" & xml(Prop, "column"))
With lblStatus
    .Visible = True
    .Caption = Text
    .Alignment = vbRightJustify
    .WordWrap = False
    .AutoSize = True
    .top = Index * (lblStatus.height)
    .left = MaxWidth - Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 15
    .Width = StatusForm.TextWidth(Text)
End With
```

I created three of these controls, but they continue to expand from the left, rather than from the right:

[image: Left-justified labels]

Ideally, I want those labels (surrounded by `#`) to have their semicolons line up.

Comment: Hmmm..tried omitting that explicit definition of the ".left" property?

Comment: @DavidW The `left` property (AFAIK) is the only way to set their horizontal positioning. I tried looking for a `right`, but was unable to find one. I need them to be "lefted" to the middle where their semicolons match up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you set `AutoSize` to true, the width is set to the precise width of the text, leaving no room for alignment.

To layout the text within a fixed width, turn off AutoSize.

Comment: This did the trick- the width was too small to allow justification. I removed the `AutoSize` property and changed the `Width` to something larger than the `TextWidth(text)` and it justified perfectly.